# Prove a set is basis for a quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=${$(x_1,...,x_5)|\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i = 0$} $w = (1,0,1,0,-2), W=span(w), v_1=(1,-1,0,0,0), v_2=(1,0,-1,0,0), v_3=(0,0,0,1,-1)$

Prove that $B = ${$v_1+W,v_2+W,v_3+W$} is a basis for $V/W$

I can prove the linear independence of B and show $span(B)\subset V/W$, but I can't prove the other direction. I think that I need to prove that for all $x_1,...x_5,c \in R$, and for some $c_1,...c_4 \in R$, $(x_1+c,x_2,x_3+c,x_4,x_5-2c) = (c_1+c_2+c_4,-c_1,c_4-c_2,c_3,-c_3-2c_4)$,  but I don't know how to proceed next.

Answer (score 1):

We know, If $U$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ then any set of linearly independent vectors of size $n$ forms a basis. We can easily show this here.
Take a linear combination of given three vectors $v_1 + W, v_2+ W, v_3 + W$

Here,
$c_1(v_1+W) +c_2(v_2+W) +c_3(v_3+W) =W$
This implies,
$c_1 v_1$+$c_2v_2$+$c_3v_3$ $\in W $
That implies $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$
It is obvious to show.
Now, this linearly independent set contains 3 vectors.

dimension of $V=4$(Think why)
dimension of $W=1$ ( It is obvious since $W$ is span of $v$)

dimension of $\frac{V}{W}= 3$
Hence This LI set forms a basis.

Comment: Legendary solution